# Slack bot cannot post message to private channel

Tags: bots, private, channel, slack

I follow [Slack bot post message documents](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)

it works perfectly when post to public channel, but get error `[error] => channel_not_found`  when post to private channel, I even change channel_name to channel ID (ex: `G1HCG4BQ9`)

I already authorized with both `chat:write:user` and `chat:write:bot` permissions

Answer (score 70):

Did you invite the bot to the channel?  A bot can't post in a private channel if it's not a member - you need to invite it to the channel like you would a person.

@YourBotsName will do it!

Comment: Official docs are [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). Search for **Post to a private group**

Comment: This worked! I clicked on the bot name and selected add bot to this channel

Comment: this worked for me! should be marked as an accepted answer!

Comment: Just a note that this answer still works 5 years later! (It's great when stuff *doesn't* change!

Answer (score 12):

i had the same issue. for getting a message in private channel you just need to manually add your app there [image]

Comment: You reply answers exactly how to invite the bot to the (especially private) channel! Thanks a ton (pray)

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same issue and was able to solve it by using [chat.postEphemeral](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral) with the `OAuth Access Token` available in the `OAuth & Permissions` page of your app configuration, which should be accessible at https://api.slack.com/apps/APP-ID-GOES-HERE/oauth

Note that there are two different token types, the `OAuth Access Token` and `Bot User OAuth Access Token`.  When I tried using the `Bot User OAuth Access Token` to send an ephemeral message to a user while they were in a private chat with another user, I received the same error message as you: `channel_not_found`, however, it worked properly when using the `OAuth Access Token`.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types) for details regarding the different token types.

Comment: The `OAuth Access Token` does not appear by default, you need to grant the app some User Token Scopes and reinstall the app, then the  `OAuth Access Token` will appear, alongside the  `Bot User OAuth Access Token`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. You need to add your bot manually in the private channel with the slack command invite

```
/invite @yourBotName
```

Don't forgot to add OAuthS Scope `chat:write` from `Features/OAuth & Permissions`

Comment: `groups:write` scope, too.

Answer (score 1):

Sam Mullin answer is correct, it's the first point you need to look at.

But for me even that didn't work out. I didn't consider incoming webhook(https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks), because that's also an option, but not in my case.

The thing that got me progressing is that slack has "Tester" tab for testing requests in its api method f.e. https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test. When you fill out the data and submit, the request you see in url also consists "token" and "pretty" arguments. I've added token argument only to authorization header, which didn't work for me, so I've added it also as param. For pretty argument I set same as text message.

I'm not sure about security issues, when passing token directly,somebody could correct me on that. But that's a variant that worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, you have to add the app to the desired private channel manually.

Answer (score 0):

It only worked for me when I added `message.groups`
on `Subscribe to bot events`.
Before just on public channels.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try setting explicitly `as_user: false` and using the team access token instead of the bot user's one.